# How data is stored in Ethereum blockchain?

Tags: storage, database

If I become a full node in Ethereum and retrieve the current state, how all this data is going to be stored in my physical drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on what node software you use.  [Geth](https://geth.ethereum.org) stores most of the data in one large [LevelDB](https://github.com/google/leveldb) database, so you may use LevelDB libraries to open and explore Geth files.  However particular structure of the database is undocumented and you will probably have to study Geth source code to understand it.